# Add a value from user_meta to user's "display name"?

Tags: wordpress

We have users registering on the site with:

- first_name
- last_name
- maiden_name
- nickname

Both maiden name and nickname are saved as key->value pair in user_meta.

I'd like to make it so that if a user includes a nickname and/or maiden name, we can make it so that when displayed on the site it will be:

first_name "nickname" last_name (maiden_name)

This is mainly important for when the user is the "author" of a post, or a comment.

Any ideas how I would make this work?

I *think* this can be done with an "add_filter" function but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out... although I did make a change, since 'nickname' is already used by Wordpress, I changed my thinking about that... may add it back (with a different label to avoid confusion), but for now just doing maiden name.

```
add_filter('the_author', 'full_author_name', 10, 1);

function full_author_name(){
    global $post;

    $user = $post->post_author;
    $maiden = get_user_meta($user, $key='high-school-last-name', $single=true);
    $first = get_user_meta($user, $key='first_name', $single=true);
    $last = get_user_meta($user, $key='last_name', $single=true);
    $maiden_name = !empty($maiden) ? ' ('.$maiden.') ' : '';
    $firstname = ' '.$first.' ';
    $lastname = ' '.$last.' ';
   $author = $firstname.$lastname.$maiden_name;
return $author;

}
```

I don't know if that's the *best* way to do it, but it seems to work.

Adapted from some other code I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841280/649417 -- which I adapted to make the same change to the comments author display:

```
add_filter('get_comment_author', 'my_comment_author', 10, 1);

function my_comment_author( $author = '' ) {

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );

        if (!empty($comment->user_id)){
            $user=$comment->user_id;
            $maiden = get_user_meta($user, $key='high-school-last-name', $single=true);
            $first = get_user_meta($user, $key='first_name', $single=true);
            $last = get_user_meta($user, $key='last_name', $single=true);
            $maiden_name = !empty($maiden) ? ' ('.$maiden.') ' : '';
            $firstname = ' '.$first.' ';
            $lastname = ' '.$last.' ';
             $author = $firstname.$lastname.$maiden_name;
        } else {
            $author = __('Anonymous');
        }
    return $author;
};
```